# Creating a node-pool with --enable-autoscaling results in an invalid argument

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I made a gke cluster node-pool using follow commands.

```
gcloud container node-pools create autoscale-pool --cluster cluster-xxx --zone asia-northeast1-a --machine-type e2-highmem-2 --disk-size 30 --enable-autoscaling --scopes bigquery,storage-rw --num-nodes 1 --min-nodes 1 --max-nodes 5 --enable-autorepair --enable-autoupgrade --node-labels=node-label-ap=ap,node-label-memorysort=memorysort,node-label-batchjob=batchjob,node-label=auto
```

Then I was facing the error follows.

```
ERROR: (gcloud.container.node-pools.create) ResponseError: code=400, message=Request contains an invalid argument.
```

`--enable-autoscaling` seems to be `an invalid argument`.
I can activate "Enable auto scale" in the admin panel.

No errors occurred until April 1.
Is it no longer possible to run the command with the `--enable-autoscaling` parameter?

Comment: Does your cluster have autoscaling enabled?

Comment: Yes,it has. It works properly until April 1.

Answer (score 2):

GKE Cluster Creation with **Google cloud SDK version 379.0.0** will fail with the invalid argument error when the `--enable-autoscaling` flag is used in the gcloud command line. We are experiencing an issue with Google Kubernetes Engine from April 1, 2022. Mitigation work is still underway by the Google Cloud Engineering team.

**EDIT**

There is an update that the issue has been resolved. The new version of **gcloud SDK (380)** is released and it doesn't have any issues.

So, Upgrade your **gcloud SDK version** to **380** in order to overcome this issue.

To know the current version of gcloud SDK, run the command

**`gcloud version | grep 'SDK'`**      # the resultant output will be  **`Google Cloud SDK 380.0.0`** version.